# MySQL replication not running updates in binlog

Tags: mysql, sql-update, replication

I have a number mysql servers running version 5.1.63 and whilst running some queries against the slave earlier this week, I noticed some data on the slave that should have been removed using an update statement on the master.

My initial thoughts were:

- someone on the team was updating the slave, which I have since disproved
- that the column being updated had changed

So, I investigated by running a mysql show status "table" query.  This was run against a test database on each of the servers to see what the data length was, in a lot of cases it was showing me the data length differed between servers, but on an eyeball look at the data  I could see the data was the same, so I couldn't use this method to see if there were any differences as it appears to be prone to error.

Next I ran a simple (across all dbs) row count for each table to confirm the row count was the same - it was.

I then started looking in the bin logs for replication.  I could see the update statements that should have run clearly visible in the logs, but the update never ran.

What I need to know is:

1. is replication broken?  I'm assuming it is
2. if I create new slave servers, will I encounter the same issue?
3. how do I find out the extent of the issue on my servers?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you run SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G on the slave to verify that the slave is running? It's possible there was an error running the statement on the slave and someone manually skipped it.

Comment: Are you using row-based or statement-based replication? Master & Slave are runnning the same version of MySQL?

Comment: Hi Kadaan, we run the commands on a daily basis to make sure everything is synchronised.  Thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using statement based replication then it is easily possible to end up with different results on master and slave due to badly constructed INSERT statements.

INSERT SELECT without ORDER BY, or where the ORDER BY can leave non deterministic results will cause the slaves to diverge from master.

From the MySQL site http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

> The order in which rows are returned by a SELECT statement with no
>   ORDER BY clause is not determined. This means that, when using
>   replication, there is no guarantee that such a SELECT returns rows in
>   the same order on the master and the slave; this can lead to
>   inconsistencies between them. To prevent this from occurring, you
>   should always write INSERT ... SELECT statements that are to be
>   replicated as INSERT ... SELECT ... ORDER BY column. The choice of
>   column does not matter as long as the same order for returning the
>   rows is enforced on both the master and the slave. See also Section
>   16.4.1.15, “Replication and LIMIT”.

If this has happened then your replicas have diverged and the only safe way to bring them back in line is to rebuild them from a recent backup of the master DB. The worst part of this is the error may never cause the replication to fail, yet the results are inconsistent. Normally replication fails when an UPDATE or DELETE statement affects a different number of rows than on master, this is confusing as it was not the UPDATE that actually caused the error and the only way I know to fix the issue is to inspect every INSERT query in the code base!

Comment: That was pretty much what I ended up doing at the time.  Just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Status details are from information_schema which collates data from databases statistics for Mysql instance and it never remained the same at every execution. It can be considered as just a rough estimation of data sizes in bytes but never an exact value as for index and data length. It can be used for estimations but not for cross check. For replication you may check the slave io and sql against the master is running or not. And relay-info you might see the corresponding log details from master and that of slave.

Of,course (1) way of doing is count(*) of tables EOD ensures the data in tables on master and slave are consistent or not. But to be accurate either (2) take random value fields and cross check with master and slave. Also if you aren't satisfied with it, (3) you may take them into outfile and take diff or checksum. I prefer (1) and (2). If (1) is not possible (2) still convinces me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool to verify replication named pt-table-checksum